# regex python for matching exact number of characters with overlapping matches

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have a a string 
`t = "abftababcd"`
I want to match a pattern 
`p= "abXX"` 
where X is a wild card and matches any character. For the given p and t I want to get 
`['abft', 'abab','abcd']`
For `p="XXab"` the expected output is `['ftab', 'abab']`

Now i want to match all the overlapping matches in string t. I have tried replacing X with 
`"ab\w{no.of X}"`
This doesn't give overlapping matches. So i tried lookahead assertion as
`"ab(?=(\w{no.of X}))"` 
Then this only gives me the matches with the pattern "ab". Also, does lookahead work if X is present in the beginning `XXab` of the string or in the middle`aXXXb`?

Comment: Given your `t` and `p`, can you update your question to tell us what is it that you expect to be extracted from t? Is it `abft` and `abab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match

```
(?=(ab..))
```

Capture group 1 contains each match, which for the string

```
"abftababcd"
```

are `"abft"`, `"abab"` and `"abcd"`.

The expression consists of a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the current position in the string is followed immediately by `'ab'` followed by any two characters, with those four characters being saved to capture group 1.

Think of positions as locations between successive characters or before the first character in the string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QGeLO6/1)

Comment: I am using regex in python. Your solution works, but only if i use findall(). But, when i use the same pattern in finditer(), it returns the empty strings as the matches, even though the indices are correct. finditer() returns [((0,0),""), ((4,4),""),((6,6),"")] for the above example, whereas findall() returns ['abft', 'abab','abcd'] . Could you tell me why this is happenning?

Comment: Perhaps a Python-person could answer Sharon's question.